# Swift DateFormatter can't read class property, returns empty string

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to pass a text label value, a date converted to a string using DateFormatter. Here is my logic thread:

I first tested the method in Playground:

```
let currentDateTime1 = Date()  // "Feb 23, 2018 at 9:09 AM"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // "2/23/18"
dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime1) // "2/23/18"
```

Success !! This is the format I need for my label

However after debugging my code I found this logic was returning nil from this code block:

```
//Event.swift

    class Event {

        var title: String = "Hello"
        var time = Date()
        init(title: String, time: Date) {
            self.title = title
            self.time = time
        }

        var events = [Event]()

    // TableViewController.swift

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var events = [Event]()

    func setDateFormatter() {
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

    }

    }

         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCell")!

                let event = events[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.text = event.title
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: event.time)
                return cell
            }
```

In the debug window I run:

```
(lldb) po event.title
"Swift 1.0"

(lldb) po event.time
▿ 2018-02-23 14:55:08 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 541090508.07748997

(lldb) po dateFormatter.string(from: event.time)
""
```

I've been stuck here a while trying to tinker and research this issue to no avail.

Can someone please help ???

Comment: Could you show the code for the event class ? please

Comment: You aren't getting `nil`. You are getting an empty string. Update your question showing how you setup `dateFormatter` in your real code.

Comment: I did add it to my question as well

Comment: Where and when do you call the `setDateFormatter` function?

Comment: I hadn't called it. Just called it in viewDidLoad and success my labels are populated !!! Thanks